# Is there a better way to write business logic to validate mutually exclusive codes?

Tags: c#, business-logic

I have two properties. I need to validate these properties against a rather large matrix showing compatible values.

**Sample properties:**

```
public string firstValue { get; set; }
public string lastValue { get; set; }
```

**Sample matrix:**

```
    A   B   C
A   X   O   O
B   O   X   X
C   X   O   X
```

Let the x axis represents the "firstValue" and the y axis represents the "lastValue". The program must validate that invalid combinations denoted by an "X" throw an error to the user.

**Sample validation:**

```
if (firstValue == "A")
{
    if (lastValue == "A" || lastValue =="C)
        Console.WriteLine("Invalid Combination");
}
```

This could obviously be refactored several ways using if\else and switch logic, but when you add many hundreds of values to the matrix it starts to get scary. I decided to create a new class containing one function per row in the matrix.

```
public class MutuallyExclusiveValidation
{
    public void CheckA(string lastValue)
    {
        if (lastValue == "A" || lastValue == "C")
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Invalid Combination");
        }
    }

    public void CheckB(string lastValue)
    {
        if (lastValue == "B")
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Invalid Combination");
        }
    }

    public void CheckC(string lastValue)
    {
        if (lastValue == "B" || lastValue == "C")
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Invalid Combination");
        }
    }
}
```

Then I devised something like this to make sure I'm not hitting more code than I need to. The predicate will return a boolean selecting and invoking the validation method that needs to be run. (just a sample, not production code)

```
    public static void CheckForMutuallyExclusiveValues(string firstValue, string lastvalue)
    {
        var allValidators = GetMutuallyExclusiveValidators(firstValue, lastvalue);
        var requiredValidators = allValidators.First(x => x.Key(firstValue));
        var validationClassInstance = new MutuallyExclusiveValidation();
        requiredValidators.Value(validationClassInstance);
    }

    public static Dictionary<Predicate<string>, Action<MutuallyExclusiveValidation>> GetMutuallyExclusiveValidators(string firstValue, string lastvalue)
    {
        var returnDictionary = new Dictionary<Predicate<string>, Action<MutuallyExclusiveValidation>>();
        Action<MutuallyExclusiveValidation> validation;
        Predicate<string> condition;

        validation = x => x.CheckA(lastvalue);
        condition = x => x == "A";
        returnDictionary.Add(condition, validation);

        validation = x => x.CheckB(lastvalue);
        condition = (x => x == "B");
        returnDictionary.Add(condition, validation);

        validation = x => x.CheckC(lastvalue);
        condition = (x => x == "C");
        returnDictionary.Add(condition, validation);

        return returnDictionary;
    }
```

This seems to work great, but I can't help thinking there's a better way. Any thoughts?

EDIT: Fabjan's answer is the one I'm going with for this particular problem. Thanks also to Tim Schmelter.

Comment: Why is `x=c|y=b` invalid?

Comment: @TimSchmelter - If you reference the matrix, invalid combinations (denoted by an "X") are AA, AC, BB, CB, CC

Comment: Why can't you just make a 2D boolean array and check against it?

Comment: @TimSchmelter I may have written it incorrectly but the x axis (left to right) comes first.

Comment: @Tresto: is there any logic, so that you f.e. can't use same first/last value or is the matrix arbitrary/predefined by the user?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a 2d array and validate records with it using some method, something like:

```
class MyClass
{
    bool[,] matrix = new bool[,]
    {            
        {false, true, false},  // x1 y123
        {true, false, true},   // x2 y123
        {true, false, false},  // x3 y123
    };

    string[] xValues = { "A", "B", "C" };
    string[] yValues = { "A", "B", "C" };

    public bool IsValid(string value1, string value2)
    {
        return matrix[Array.IndexOf(xValues, value1), Array.IndexOf(yValues, value2)];
    }
}


class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        MyClass c = new MyClass();

        Console.WriteLine(c.IsValid("A", "A"));

        Console.WriteLine(c.IsValid("B", "C"));

        Console.WriteLine(c.IsValid("A", "C"));

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

Output:

[image: Output]

Answer (score 3):

You could use a `Dictionary<string, HashSet<string>>` to store the X-value as key and all invalid Y-values as values.

```
Dictionary<string, HashSet<string>> InvalidValues = new Dictionary<string, HashSet<string>> { 
    {"A", new HashSet<string>{"A", "C"}},
    {"B", new HashSet<string>{"B"}},
    {"C", new HashSet<string>{"B", "C"}}
};
```

Now you can check efficiently if given x- and y-values are invalid:

```
var emptySet = new HashSet<string>();
var invalidValues = allValues
    .Where(x => InvalidValues.TryGet(x.FirstValue, emptySet).Contains(x.LastValue));
foreach (Value val in invalidValues)
    Console.WriteLine("Invalid Combination: {0}|{1}", val.FirstValue, val.LastValue);
```

used this extension to linqify `Dictionary.TryGetValue`:

```
public static TValue TryGet<TKey, TValue>(this Dictionary<TKey, TValue> dict, TKey key, TValue defaultValue = default(TValue))
{
    TValue value;
    bool success = dict.TryGetValue(key, out value);
    if (success)
        return value;
    else
        return defaultValue;
}
```

this class:

```
public class Value
{
    public string FirstValue { get; set; }
    public string LastValue { get; set; }
}
```

and some sample values:

```
var allValues = new List<Value> { 
    new Value { FirstValue = "A", LastValue = "C" }, 
    new Value { FirstValue = "A", LastValue = "B" }, 
    new Value { FirstValue = "B", LastValue = "C" }, 
    new Value { FirstValue = "A", LastValue = "A" } 
};
```